# Testing for multiple flag values

Tags: c#, enum-flags

I have this flag enumeration:

```
public enum AssignmentType
{
    None = 0,
    Attendant = 1,
    ConductorCBS = 2,
    ReaderCBS = 4,
    Chairman = 8,
    Mike = 16,
    PlatformAttendant = 32,
    Prayer = 64,
    OCLM = 128,
    Sound = 256,
    Student = 512,
    Custom = 1024,
    Demonstration = 2048,
    Assistant = 4096
}
```

I am now wanting to test my variable for a certain flag condition.

I want to identify my variable is **only any combination of**:

- `None`
- `Student`
- `Assistant`
- `Demonstration`

So if it has any of the other enumeration values the variable would not satisfy the test.

At first I started with this:

```
bool bIsPersonnel = true;

if (_Assignments == AssignmentType.None ||
    _Assignments == AssignmentType.Demonstration || 
    _Assignments == AssignmentType.Student ||
    _Assignments == AssignmentType.Assistant ||
    _Assignments == (AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Student))
{
    bIsPersonnel = false;
}
```

But I quickly realised the multiple choices there are.

Is there a simpler way?

I can't see how to suggested answer helps. I guess it is easiest to do my test in reverse. Just test if it has any of the **other flags** then I know it is personnel!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \[Flags\] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Comment: @mjwills Yes, if it is set to `None` then no other flags should be set anyway. But, the possibilities here are several configurations. I just wondered if there was a simpler way to do the test.

Comment: Slightly simpler is to use Enum.HasFlag().

Comment: @meJustAndrew Please see my proposed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a mask with the `~` bitwise negation operator to find all the *invalid* flags, and check whether any have been applied.

```
var valid = AssignmentType.Student | AssignmentType.Assistant | AssignmentType.Demonstration;
var invalid = ~valid; // Everything that isn't valid

if ((_Assignments & invalid) != 0)
{
    // There was at least one invalid flag, handle it appropriately
}
```

Or to check whether it's valid:

```
if ((_Assignment & invalid) == 0)
{
    // There are no invalid flags, handle it appropriately
}
```

Or if you're just after setting a single boolean flag, you don't need an `if` statement at all:

```
bool isPersonnel = ((assignment & invalid) != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. So this would equate to a simplified version of what I put in my proposed answer?

Comment: Your code raises a syntax error about using `&` to compare `AssignmentType` and `bool`.

Comment: I think you'll need to check for the `AssignmentType.None` state separately, because if `_Assignments == AssignmentType.None` then `(_Assignments & invalid != 0)` will be false (and the OP wants it to be true in that situation).

Comment: Please update your answer so that when I paste it into VC it does not raise a error. Thanks. 

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Fixed with a pair of brackets. Should be fine now.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I see no indication that the OP wants it to be true - the question says that it's *okay* to include `AssignmentType.None`, which is a good job, as any value "includes" 0.

Answer (score 2):

(Incorrect answer)

```
if ((_Assignments & AssignmentType.None) > 0
    || (_Assignments & AssignmentType.Student) > 0
    || (_Assignments & AssignmentType.Assistant) > 0
    || (_Assignments & AssignmentType.Demonstration) > 0
){
    bIsPersonnel = false;
}
```

Corrected answer:

```
var NonPersonnel = AssignmentType.None | AssignmentType.Student | AssignmentType.Assistant | Demonstration;
bool bIsPersonnel = (_Assignments | NonPersonnel) != NonPersonnel;
```

Comment: But that is only testing if each of those flags is set. It is ignoring the fact that the other flags might also be set. Correct?

Comment: @Andrew Truckle you are right, my answer is incorrect. I'll try to come up with something else.

Comment: See my answer and if it can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works as expected:

```
var flags =
    AssignmentType.None
    | AssignmentType.Student
    | AssignmentType.Assistant
    | AssignmentType.Demonstration;

bool bIsPersonnel =
    !(_Assignments == AssignmentType.None
        || (flags & _Assignments) == _Assignments);
```

Here is some sample output:

```
_Assignments = AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Assistant; // False
_Assignments = AssignmentType.None; // False
_Assignments = AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Mike; // True
```

Comment: You can miss out the `AssignmentType.None` part of the assignment to `flags` because it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have come up with doing the reverse test:

```cs
bool bIsPersonnel = false;

if(_Assignments.HasFlag(AssignmentType.Attendant | AssignmentType.ConductorCBS |
    AssignmentType.ReaderCBS | AssignmentType.Chairman |
    AssignmentType.Mike | AssignmentType.PlatformAttendant |
    AssignmentType.Prayer | AssignmentType.OCLM |
    AssignmentType.Sound | AssignmentType.Custom))
{
    bIsPersonnel = true;
}
```

This is easiest because we know that if any one of those flags are set the person is "Personnel". The other flags are out of the picture and we don't have to test for multiple flag configurations.

Comment: this is far too inefficient, `_Assignments.HasFlag(AssignmentType.Attendant | AssignmentType.ConductorCBS | AssignmentType.ReaderCBS...)` would be better

Comment: @phuclv Updated.

Comment: @phuclv I reverted my code. I found that I had to have **all** of the above flags  satisfied for it to be true where as I wanted **any one** of them for it to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a mask of values to check and `and` the mask with the value, that's how flags are checked, regardless of only the number of flags

```
if (0 != _Assignments &
     (AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Student | AssignmentType.Assistant))
```

No need to check `AssignmentType.None` because it's not a flag itself, just a reserved value that's equal to 0, used for checking that none of the flag is set. If the combination contains both "no flag" and "some other flag" then it doesn't make sense, right? If you do need to check the "no flag" condition then check it separately

```
if (_Assignments == AssignmentType.None || (0 != _Assignments &
         (AssignmentType.Demonstration | AssignmentType.Student | AssignmentType.Assistant)))
```

That's also how [`Enum.HasFlag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.7.2) checks the flags

> ```
> public static void Main()
> {
>    DinnerItems myOrder = DinnerItems.Appetizer | DinnerItems.Entree |
>                         DinnerItems.Beverage | DinnerItems.Dessert;
>    DinnerItems flagValue = DinnerItems.Entree | DinnerItems.Beverage;
>    Console.WriteLine("{0} includes {1}: {2}", 
>                      myOrder, flagValue, myOrder.HasFlag(flagValue));
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but again you are missing the point that the **other** flags might be set. See my own answer that might explain it clearer.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "other flags might be set"? You're checking if the variable has any bits among the flags enabled, right? This one does exactly that, returning true if only at least one of the specified flags are set. How on earth is other bits related here?

Comment: We are looking to to see if they **only** have the stated flags. So if they also have, say `Attendant` then they don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: `Attendant` isn't among `Demonstration | Student | Assistant`, so if the Attendant isn't `Demonstration | Student | Assistant` obviously the condition is true, and `bIsPersonnel` will be false as expected

Comment: OK, sorry! I easily get confused with flags. Thanks!